# Create a two new column by mapping multiple column

Tags: r

How to match columns in R and extract value. As an example: I want to match on the basis of Name and City columns of dataframe_one with dataframe_two and then return the output with two another column temp and ID. If it matches it should return TRUE and ID too.

My input is:

dataframe_one

```
Name    City
Sarah   ON
David   BC
John    KN
Diana   AN
Judy    ON
```

dataframe_two

```
Name    City    ID
Dave    ON     1092
Diana   AN     2314
Judy    ON     1290
Ari     KN     1450
Shanu   MN     1983
```

I want the output to be

```
Name    City    temp    ID
Sarah   ON   FALSE     NA
David   BC   TRUE     1450
John    KN   TRUE     1983
Diana   AN   FALSE    NA
Judy    ON   FALSE    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that makes answering questions of this type easier is if you at least put the data frames in R, like so:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  Name = c("Sarah", "David", "John", "Diana", "Judy"),
                  City = c("ON", "BC", "KN", "AN", "ON")
)

df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  Name = c("Dave", "Diana", "Judy", "Ari", "Shanyu"),
                  City = c("ON", "AN", "ON", "KN", "MN"),
                  ID = c(1092, 2314, 1290, 1450, 1983)
)
```

Then search existing Stack Overflow questions that have answered similar questions (e.g. [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right/1300618#1300618)).

Given that neither of your original dfs contain the column "Temp" you would need to create it in the joined (merged) data frame.
We'll be able to help a lot more if you at least make a start and then the community will help you troubleshoot.

That being said, I can't for the life of me figure out how you would generate your output df from the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Using **biomiha** code to generate df1 and df2:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  Name = c("Sarah", "David", "John", "Diana", "Judy"),
                  City = c("ON", "BC", "KN", "AN", "ON")
)

df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  Name = c("Dave", "Diana", "Judy", "Ari", "Shanyu"),
                  City = c("ON", "AN", "ON", "KN", "MN"),
                  ID = c(1092, 2314, 1290, 1450, 1983)
)
```

you may try:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("Name" = "Name", "City" = "City")) %>%
  mutate(temp = !is.na(ID))
```

gives the output:

```
   Name City   ID  temp
1 Sarah   ON   NA FALSE
2 David   BC   NA FALSE
3  John   KN   NA FALSE
4 Diana   AN 2314  TRUE
5  Judy   ON 1290  TRUE
```